# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to instantiate the Webdriver driver under @ Annotation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

Please find the code below and let me know why am I getting NullPointer. I am having no clue.

```
package com.seleniumhybridframework.utility;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class BrowserFactory {

    public BrowserFactory() {
        super();

    }

    public static WebDriver startApplication(WebDriver driver, String browser, String appURL) {

    if(browser.equals("Chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }   

    else if(browser.equals("Firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drivers/geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
    }

    else if(browser.equals("InternetExplorer")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.IE.driver", "./drivers/IE.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();      
    }

    else
        System.out.println("Provided browser is invalid");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(appURL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return driver;
    }

    public static void closeBrowser(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

LoginPage:

```
package com.seleniumhybridframework.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;


public class LoginPage {


    WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver ldriver) {
        this.driver = ldriver;

    }



    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[href=\"https://ui.freecrm.com\"]") WebElement loginLink;
    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="email") WebElement username;
    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="password") WebElement password;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//div[text()=\"Login\"]") WebElement loginButton;

    public void loginApp(String emailId, String passWord) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Timed Out");
        }

        loginLink.click();
        username.sendKeys(emailId);
        password.sendKeys(passWord);
        loginButton.click();

    }

}
```

BaseClass:

```
package com.seleniumhybridframework.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import com.seleniumhybridframework.utility.BrowserFactory;
import com.seleniumhybridframework.utility.ConfigDataProvider;
import com.seleniumhybridframework.utility.ExcelReader;
import com.seleniumhybridframework.utility.Helper;

public class BaseClass {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public ExcelReader excel;
    public ConfigDataProvider config;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setupSuite() {
        excel = new ExcelReader("./testData/", "Data1.xlsx");
        config = new ConfigDataProvider("./configFiles/config.properties");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println(config.getValue("appURL"));
        BrowserFactory.startApplication(driver, config.getBrowser(), config.getValue("appURL"));
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void teardown() {
        BrowserFactory.closeBrowser(driver);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDownMethod(ITestResult result) {
        if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            Helper.captureScreenshot(driver);
        }


    }

}
```

LoginCRM:

```
package com.seleniumhybridframework.testCases;


import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.seleniumhybridframework.pages.BaseClass;
import com.seleniumhybridframework.pages.LoginPage;


public class LoginCRM extends BaseClass{



    @Test
    public void loginToCRM() {

        LoginPage loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        loginpage.loginApp(excel.getStringData(0, 0, 0), excel.getStringData(0, 0, 1));

    }
}
```

Error Result--

```
FAILED: loginToCRM
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.seleniumhybridframework.pages.LoginPage.loginApp(LoginPage.java:38)
    at com.seleniumhybridframework.testCases.LoginCRM.loginToCRM(LoginCRM.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: Can you please format your code and post?

Comment: I can see my code formatted only. What do you mean by formatting it , can you explain?

Comment: The code has been formatted right now by João Farias. You can learn how to format by the code at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks You can add language-specific tag (like `java`) to have your syntax hightlighted.

Comment: Your NPE is on the line 38 of the loginApp method. Which line is it? _loginLink.click();_, _username.sendKeys(emailId);_, _password.sendKeys(passWord);_, or _loginButton.click()_?

Comment: NPE is occurring on loginLink.click();

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate driver in BaseClass.

You need to intialize the elements using PageFactory class in LoginPage constructor.

```
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {           this.driver = driver; PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); }
```

Create LoginPage class object in test as

```
LoginPage loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

Comment: Hi Anupam, I tried that also but still getting the same error. Can you please give me detailed answer.

Comment: I saw the code but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I can figure out these things

1- You have not instantiated pageFactory in LoginPage class. Please do it using below

```
      public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){

      PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }
```

2-In loginToCRM class create object of LoginPage as given below.

```
     LoginPage loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

3-Can you also try in LoginPage class

```
 @FindBy(xpath= "//a[href=\"https://ui.freecrm.com\"]") 
 WebElement loginLink;
```

behalf of this

```
 @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[href=\"https://ui.freecrm.com\"]") 
 WebElement loginLink
```

try above steps simultaneously.Hope it will be helpfull. If not then please let us know line no 38 in LoginPage class.